# JMeter Sampler with SLF4J

Tags: jmeter, slf4j

I have a JMeter Java Sampler that extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient.

I'd like to use SLF4J & LogBack as my logger rather than:

```
import org.apache.jorphan.logging.LoggingManager;
import org.apache.log.Logger;
```

Ideally I'd like the sampler logs to also go to the `jmeter.log` file.

Any have any success with this and where do you configure `logback.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found I just needed to do the following before calling jmeter.bat

```
set JVM_ARGS=-Dlogback.debug=true -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml
```